# Sending sqlcmd utility errors to file

Tags: sqlcmd

I am working on `sqlcmd` utility. I want to store errors in a file instead of printing those on console.

I saw there are several options like `:Error` etc. but I am not getting how to use those. I have read `sqlcmd` official documentation but it is not clear how to send error to a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can [redirect the output of a command](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-be/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout) to a file using the `>` output redirection:

```
sqlcmd [your sqlcmd options here] > "your_path_here\Errors.txt"
```